# How to complete the proof of the theorem about associative property?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, associativity

Let $A$ be set of numbers. Prove that if * operation is associative for any $3$ elements from $A$, the operation is associative for any $n$ elements from $A$, too.
Intuitively, this can be proved by the method of Mathematical Induction, but I don't know how to go further after inductive step.

Comment: What would the associative property for, for instance, four elements look like? $(abc)d=a(bcd)$? Something else?

Comment: What does "associative for $n$ elements" mean?

Comment: @Arthur Please look at **Generalized associative law** section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)